# Xelatex vs Lualatex relatively to PetiteCaps

Tags: luatex, font-features

Please, try this simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+pcap]{EB Garamond}
\newrobustcmd\lin[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}#1}}
\newrobustcmd\textpc[1]{{\addfontfeature{Letters=PetiteCaps}#1}}

\begin{document}

\textsc{abcde fghijk lmnop qrstu vwxyz}

\textpc{abcde fghijk lmnop qrstu vwxyz}

\end{document}
```

Xelatex produces PetiteCaps, Lualatex don't.
What's wrong or missing? RawFeature=+pcap is irrelevant.

Thank you

**PS**

In Xelatex .log I read:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'EBGaramond(0)' created for font 'EB
(fontspec)             Garamond' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Latin,Language=Italian,Numbers={Pr
oportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+pcap].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+pcap;
mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+smcp;
mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+pca
p;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+smc
p;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+pca
p;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+smc
p;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+pc
ap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;+sm
cp;mapping=tex-text;"
.
.
.
Requested font "EB Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Regular.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBoldItalic.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Regular.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBold.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Regular.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Italic.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Regular.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Regular.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBold.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBold.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Italic.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-Italic.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBoldItalic.otf
Requested font "EB Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaram
ond-SemiBoldItalic.otf
```

On the contrary, in Lualatex .log I read:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Italian' not available for font
(fontspec)                'EBGaramond' with script 'Latin'.

luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) does not define feature pcap for script latn
 with language dflt

Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Letters=PetiteCaps' (pcap) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'EBGaramond' with script 'Latin'
(fontspec)                and language 'Italian'.

luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature pcap for script latn
 with language dflt
```

Comment: works fine for me. Check the font pathes, perhaps lualatex finds another font. You can use `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to get pathes in the log for xelatex.

Comment: I suspect you have the original EB Garamond installed on your system, and Pardo’s version in TeX Live; luatex would use the former.

Comment: the font path used by lualatex is at the end of the log.

Comment: Yes and not: I've a full version (but the last Pardo version)  in /usr/local/share/font installed by me, but the original version included in Texlive

Comment: Yest: I've a full version (but the last Pardo version: 1.1 rev 1,00101)  in /usr/local/share/font installed by me, and the  version included in Texlive, which is /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Regular.otf (version 001.000). This is confusing. Better the more recent, eliminating that one of texlive? or is it dangerous? Or is there a way to say Lualatex which version to use?

Comment: Each version has its advantages; which you prefer will depend on your needs. You can have both installed and specify the path. And I do wish Pardo’s version included some modification of the name!

Comment: well you wrote that xelatex works for you, and xelatex is using the one in usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond so I wouldn't delete that.

Comment: @ulrikefischer: not at all, because it's only a test. I'm using lualatex with \babelfont, not xelatex and \setmainfont

Comment: Sure but lualatex doesn't work correctly for you, which means it uses the wrong font, while xelatex uses the right one.

Comment: Yes, undoubtedly. Can I tell Lualatex to use the most recent versione by \defaultfontfeatures to verify if the fault is of the latest version??